# jQuery Cross Domain Request JSON: Cannot read property 'json' of null

Tags: jquery, json, yql

I´m trying to get a JSON from an external url. Due to Cross Domain-issues, I use the yahoo YQL service.

I get an error: *Cannot read property 'json' of null*

Thank you for your tips!

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    error: function() {
     alert('There is an error with rawdata');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        
  schema = [];
  object = [];
  data = [];
  
        var schema = response.query.results.json.schema;
        var options = response.query.results.json.options;
        var data = response.query.results.json.data;

        console.log( "schema: ",  schema ); // server response
        console.log( "options: ",  options ); // server response
        console.log( "data: ",  data ); // server response

         //$("#productEditor").alpaca("destroy");
      //jsonEditor(schema, options, data);

        
    }, data: {
        q: "select * from json where url=\"https://www.webongo.de/data.json?format=json?callback=?\"",
        format: "json"
    },
    
           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `null` check on the json response, see the updated code

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    error: function() {
     alert('There is an error with rawdata');
    },
    success: function(response) {

  schema = [];
  object = [];
  data = [];
  if(response.query.results!==null){
          var schema = response.query.results.json.schema;
          var options = response.query.results.json.options;
          var data = response.query.results.json.data;

          console.log( "schema: ",  schema ); // server response
          console.log( "options: ",  options ); // server response
          console.log( "data: ",  data ); // server response

         //$("#productEditor").alpaca("destroy");
      //jsonEditor(schema, options, data);
       }else{
            console.log("Results returns null");
       }
    }, data: {
        q: "select * from json where url=\"https://www.webongo.de/data.json?format=json?callback=?\"",
        format: "json"
    },
    
           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you. now, it do not get an error, but i still get not the objects.